# Vaadin Flow @Route annotation with layout set breaks layout style

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin12

I'm using Vaadin 12.0.3 and I'm trying to create a top menu bar using an `AppLayout`. Therefore I added the `AppLayout`, which contains the Menu to my main view - the `DashboardView` (which extends `RouterLayout`). This view should be the parent view for the `MonitoringView` which displays some data. Therefore I'm setting the `@Route` annotation to the `MonitoringView` like this: `@Route(Monitoring.route, layout = DashboardView::class)`.

The problem is if I add `layout = DashboardView::class` to the annotation all styling of the `MonitoringView` is gone. This means texts are not displayed, (background-)colors and shadows are gone and so one. When I remove the layout part from the annotation everything looks fine but then I can't see the menu bar on top.

Here's the code for the mentioned classes:

The `DashboardView`, which should be the parent for the other view and contains the menu (`AppLayout`):

```
@UIScope
@SpringComponent
@Route("dashboard")
@PageTitle("Dashboard")
class DashboardView() : VerticalLayout(), BeforeEnterObserver, RouterLayout {

    init {
        val appLayout = AppLayout()
        val menu = appLayout.createMenu()

        menu.addMenuItems(
                AppLayoutMenuItem("Page 1", "monitoring"),
                AppLayoutMenuItem("Page 2")
        )

        add(appLayout)
    }
}
```

The `MonitoringView` that shows monitoring data and should be displayed below the menu bar when the user clicks on "Page 1":

```
@UIScope
@SpringComponent
@Route("monitoring", layout = DashboardView::class)
class MonitoringView() : VerticalLayout(), BeforeEnterObserver {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you check if you are facing same issue as described here: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-app-layout-flow/issues/61 ?

Comment: Thank you! But I don't think it relates as I'm not using the `AbstractRouterLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `@Route` property `layout` needs the java class instead of the Kotlin class?

Try `layout = DashboardView::class.java`.

See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html

> Note that a Kotlin class reference is not the same as a Java class
>   reference. To obtain a Java class reference, use the .java property on
>   a KClass instance.

Comment: Actually I'm surprised that `DashboardView::class` even compiles in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately it's the other way round DashboardView::class.java doesn't compile because it's expecting `KClass<out RouterLayout>`
But thanks for your help!

Comment: The error I get when using this is: Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: 
required:
KClass<out RouterLayout!>
found:
Class<DashboardView>